# SQL: Query to get rows where the user was present for at least 1 day of a given month, year

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

How do I get all rows where the user was present for at least 1 day in March 2019 (1st -31st March, 2019). That 1 day can be either in start date or end date or both.

---

Table

```
| userid  | startdate | enddate |. postid
| ------- | --------- | ------  | -----
| u1 | 01-01-2019 | 03-05-2019. |  s1
| u1 | 03-06-2019 | 03-22-2019. |. s1
| u1 | 03-23-2019 | 05-20-2019. |  s3
| u2 | 03-01-2019 | 12-31-2099. |. s1
| u3 | 01-01-2019 | 04-20-2019. |  s2
| u4 | 01-04-2013 | 08-22-2020. |  s3
| u4 | 05-20-2020 | 12-31-2099. |  s3
```

Expected Result:

```
| userid  | startdate | enddate |. postid
| ------- | --------- | ------  | -----
| u1 | 01-01-2019 | 03-05-2019. |  s1
| u1 | 03-06-2019 | 03-22-2019. |. s1
| u1 | 03-23-2019 | 05-20-2019. |  s3
| u2 | 03-01-2019 | 12-31-2099. |. s1
| u3 | 01-01-2019 | 04-20-2019. |  s2
| u4 | 01-04-2013 | 08-22-2020. |  s3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for overlaps between the stored periods and the month of March 2019 like this:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where end_date >= '2019-03-01' and start_date <= '2019-03-31'
```